# convert 1,00 to 100 in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I convert the number "1,00" to "100" in .Net?

**Clarification:** I have this code:

```
VALOR = order.Total.ToString("#0.00");
```

It returns the text "1,00" but I need "100" (without comma).

Comment: is a currency and i need in str without

Comment: Which language syntax? C#, VB.NET, or something more obscure that might support 1,00 not as a string?

Comment: Is this your only use case, or is there possibly a more generalized description of your problem?

Comment: i have this code: 
VALOR = order.Total.ToString("#0.00");
and it return the text : 1,00  but I need 100 (without ,)

Because I will pass this in an url

Comment: How has this question received 3 upvotes when you could have used the google?

Comment: @Michael K: Maybe a lot of people don't like to Google? Heaven forbid they're Binging instead.

Comment: @Michael K. Awesome, that's a trip down memory lane.

Comment: @Taylor L: No comment. I stop giving away my age at AltaVista which incidentally is still there http://www.altavista.com/

Comment: Why in the world are you all upvoting this!?

Answer (score 9):

```
string str = Decimal.Parse("1,00", NumberStyles.Currency).ToString();
```

This handles currency strings in a generic way. See the [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) for specifics and other options.

**Update:** Based on updated comments it sounds like your current culture is the issue. Try something like this:

```
string str = orderTotal.ToString("#0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false));
```

Comment: +1 for using culture-specific features. This is less apt to break in the future.

Comment: @Beto: You appear to be new. Welcome, and remember `you can accept any answer` by clicking the checkmark below the vote number.

Answer (score 4):

```
"1,00".ToString().Replace(",", "");
```

Replace "1,00" with whatever you're converting. This will work for currencies (*in specific localizations only*) and any other data type that supports ToString() in a logical manner.

Comment: +1 because it does exactly what is asked, although I have my doubts that this is the problem that is being solved.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to handle the culture correctly.

Comment: This answer isn't sensitive to culture settings. Likely prone to breaking in future if culture settings are the cause of the comma. Just saying, not casting judgement on answer. Question doesn't state how the comma came about.

Answer (score 3):

If 1,00 is decimal, probably you're in a culture like Spanish (Spain) where decimal separator is ',' and thousands separator is '.' then:

```
VALOR = (order.Total * 100).ToString("N0");
```

Comment: Poster is definitely in a non-English culture given original question wording before edits. Good speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 100 and round with a precision of 0?

Comment: is a currency and i need in str without ,

Answer (score 0):

Just URL encode it as it is.  Then URL decode when it will be consumed.

```
VALOR = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(VALOR);
```

You mentioned in comments on your question that you need to remove the comma because you are passing the value in a URL.  I interpreted this to mean that because commas aren't valid in urls, you just need to remove the comma for the value to pass correctly - not because you need to change the locale formatting or otherwise change the data in any way.

If that is the case, then you don't need to alter the string at all - you can simply encode it.